# Using a for loop to read and extract details from multiple abstracts

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to extract certain data from a file with many abstracts. I am able to get everything I need from a single abstract but am struggling to figure out how to implement a for loop to create a data frame with all the info required.

```
## file import
folder <- "abstracts"
files<-dir(path = folder)
abstracts <- list.files(pattern = "abstract.*.txt")
fileName <- file.path(folder,files) 

for(file in abstracts){
lines <- readLines(con = abstracts[1])
#lines

presenter <- unlist(strsplit(x = lines[1], split = ": ", fixed = TRUE))[2]
presenter

title <- unlist(strsplit(x = lines[2], split = ": ", fixed = TRUE))[2]
title

format <- unlist(strsplit(x = lines[3], split = ": ", fixed = TRUE))[2]
format

session <- unlist(strsplit(x = lines[4], split = ": ", fixed = TRUE))[2]  
session

dateandtime <- unlist(strsplit(x = lines[5], split = ": ", fixed = TRUE))[2]
date <- unlist(strsplit(dateandtime, " ", fixed = TRUE))[1]
date
time <- unlist(strsplit(dateandtime, " ", fixed = TRUE))[2]
time

allKeywords <- unlist(strsplit(x = lines[6], split = ": ", fixed = TRUE))[2]
allKeywords
sepKeywords <- strsplit(x = allKeywords, split = ", ", fixed = TRUE)
keyword1 <- unlist(sepKeywords)[1]
keyword2 <- unlist(sepKeywords)[2]
keyword3 <- unlist(sepKeywords)[3]
keyword4 <- unlist(sepKeywords)[4]
keyword5 <- unlist(sepKeywords)[5]
keyword6 <- unlist(sepKeywords)[6]

abstract <- lines[8]
abstract

df <- data.frame <- c(presenter, title, format, session, date, time, keyword1,
          keyword2, keyword3, keyword4, keyword5, keyword6, abstract)
df


}
```

I know there are errors above, but it works to get the required info from the first abstract. Both files and fileName are empty character vectors, and I'm not sure if they should be something else. Also I am unsure about the argument in the for loop. Sorry if this is a basic error but I cannot seem to correct it myself.

Comment: The first error is that we don't have your files, so nothing is found. Perhaps you can make this reproducible by adding 2-3 sample abstracts.

Comment: Write a function that takes a single abstract as an argument and returns the desired result. Then use lapply() to apply that function to a list of abstracts.